# Recursive descent in zip files?

Tags: perl, recursion, php-ziparchive

I am trying to recursively scan a bunch of zip files and I am using, of course, archive::zip. I would like to avoid expanding the archive's content in a temporary folder. I would like to be able to use something like (nearly-pseudo code):

```
sub CALLMYSELFAGAIN .....

my @members = $currentZipFile->members();
while(my $member = pop @members){                       
    if ($member->isTextFile()){
        push @content, $member->contents();
    }elsif(isZipFile($member->fileName())){
        CALLMYSELFAGAIN($member);
    }
```

The problem is, `$member->can("memberNames"))` returns false, so `$member` is NOT an archive::zip in the sense that I could not open it again as a zip file. Or am I wrong?

Any hint?

Comment: Are you having zip of directory and files or zip of zip ? It seems you are confusing the two.

Comment: If you do have a zip containing zips that you want to traverse recursively, please be aware that malicious zips are possible - you can create a zip file that unzips to an exact copy of itself, for infinite recursion (a zip quine); http://research.swtch.com/zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
elsif (isZipFile($member->filename)) {
    my $contents = $currentZipFile->contents($member);
    open my $fh, '<', \$contents; # In-memory filehandle
    my $child_zip = Archive::Zip->new;
    $child_zip->readFromFileHandle($fh);
    CALLMYSELFAGAIN($child_zip);
}
```

but expect that to be very memory intensive, especially if you go more than one level deep.

Comment: I get an error related to the fact that the file is not seekable:error: file not seekable
 at D:/Perl64/lib/Archive/Zip/Archive.pm line 576
        Archive::Zip::Archive::readFromFileHandle('Archive::Zip::Archive=HASH(0x
2c63180)', 'GLOB(0x2a5dc38)') called at _________.pm line 190
        metellib::zipDescent('filename.zip')

Comment: Anyway your answer helped me to identify a solution. Thanks