# how to use perl Archive::Zip to recursively walk archive files?

Tags: perl, archive

I have a small perl script that I use to search archives for members matching a name.  I'd like to enhance this so that if it finds any members in the archive that are also archives (zip, jar, etc) it will then recursively scan those, looking for the original desired pattern.

I've looked through the "Archive::Zip" documentation, and I thought I saw how to do this.  I noticed the "fh()" and "readFromFileHandle()" methods.  However, in my testing, it appears that the "fh()" call on an archive member returns the file handle for the containing archive, not the member.  Perhaps I'm doing it wrong, but I would appreciate an example of how to do this.

Comment: related: [recursive descent in zip files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330602/perl-recursive-descent-in-zip-files)

Comment: Coming back to this years later, I find that that related posting also lead me to a solution.  I could never get "MemberRead" to work, but using the "in-memory file handle" to open the sub-archive works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't read the contents of any sort of archive member (whether it is text, picture, or another archive) without extracting it from the archive file.

Once you have identified a member that you want to view, you must call `extractMember` (or, more likely, `extractMemberWithoutPaths` if the file is to be temporary) to extract it to a disk file. Then you can create a new `Archive::Zip` object and `read` the new file while keeping the old one open.

You will presumably want to `unlink` the archive file once you have catalogued its contents.

---

**Edit**

I hadn't come across the [`Archive::Zip::MemberRead`](https://metacpan.org/module/Archive%3a%3aZip%3a%3aMemberRead) module before. It appears you were on the right track with `readFromFileHandle`. I would guess that it should work like this, but it would be awkward for me to test it at present.

```
my $zip = Archive::Zip->new;
$zip->read('myfile.zip');

my $zipfh  = Archive::Zip::MemberRead->new($zip, 'archive/path/to/member.zip');

my $newzip = Archive::Zip->new;
$newzip->readFromFileHandle($zipfh)
```

Comment: I tried adding this, but I get an unexpected error.  I added a "use Archive::Zip::MemberRead;" statement, and a line like your "->new(" line from above, but it fails with "Can't locate object method "opened" via package "Archive::Zip::MemberRead" at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Archive/Zip/Archive.pm line 570."

Comment: Hmm. `Archive::Zip::MemberRead` is meant to emulate `IO::Handle` but it seems it is missing a method. If this is the only problem then you may want to try hacking it by adding `sub Archive::Zip::MemberRead::opened { 1 }` to the start of your program, but there may be more that needs fixing. I have emailed the author of the module about this and will try to remember to let you know the outcome. In the meantime the only other solution is to extract the zipped members to files and open them with `Archive::Zip` in the normal way.

Comment: The answer that I ended up using is described in the link in the comment for my original posting. I didn't end up using MemberRead, just an in-memory file handle.